# docx template processor inserting image

Tags: php, xml, regex, templates

I wrote own docx template processor on PHP. 
 I work with docx file as archive and change `document.xml` file in the word directory of the archive.  Everything had worked well until I inserted image. In word file, I write templates like this:

```
{(SOME_TEMPLATE)}
```

and in XML file it looks like:

```
some xml tags ... {(SOME_TEMPLATE)} ... some xml tags
```

But when I insert image after my template it looks like:

```
some tags ... { some tags ...(SOME_TEMPLATE)} ". <br />
```

Image breaks my template my XML tags. I tried to replace the template using `str_replace()` function, but is it good variant to replace it by regular expression like this?

1. At first we are searching for `{`
2. Then we ignore all symbols until we find `(`
3. Then we ignore all until we find keyword `SOME_TEMPLATE`
4. Then repeat step 2 until `)`
5. Then repeat untill `}`

Answer (score 2):

This Regex used with function `preg_replace` should do the trick :

```
\{[^(]*\(.*SOME_TEMPLATE.*\)[^\}]*\}
```

But I'm not sure that it is a very 'clean' way to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I found more cleaner solution to ignore all tags and whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody face with this problem, I found solution to write regular expression which ignores tags and whitespaces:

```
{(</?[^(a-zA-Z)]\b[^>]>|\s)*(\1*SOME_TAG\1*)\1*}
```